# Problem with Python CSV putting each letter in new field

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to put a list of URLs into a csv file that I'm scraping from a webpage using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup.  I have tried writing the links to a csv file as unicode and also converted to utf-8.  In both cases, each letter is inserted into a new field.

Here's my code (I've tried it at least these two ways):

```
f = open('filename','wb')
w = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
for link in links:
    w.writerow(link['href'])
```

And:

```
f = open('filename','wb')
w = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
for link in links:
    w.writerow(link['href'].encode('utf-8'))
```

`links` is a list that looks like this:

```
[<a href="#Flyout1" accesskey="2" class="quicklinks" tabindex="1" title="Skip to content">Quick Links: Skip to main page content</a>, <a href="#search" class="quicklinks" tabindex="1" title="Skip to search">Skip to Search</a>, <a href="#News" class="quicklinks" tabindex="1" title="Skip to Section table of contents">Skip to Section Content Menu</a>, <a href="#footer" class="quicklinks" tabindex="1" title="Skip to site options">Skip to Common Links</a>, <a href="http://www.hhs.gov"><img src="/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@system/documents/system/img_fdagov_hhs_gov.png" alt="www.hhs.gov link" style="width:112px; height:18px;" border="0" /></a>]
```

Not all the links have an `'href'` key but I check for that in code not shown here.  In both cases, the correct strings are written to the csv file, but each letter is in a new field.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#writer-objects): "A row must be a sequence of strings or numbers ..."  You are passing a single string, not a sequence of strings, so it treats each letter as an item.  Put your string in a list.

So change `w.writerow(link['href'])` to `w.writerow([link['href']])`.

**Note:** A csv file with a single column looks exactly like a flat text file.  Maybe you don't need csv.

Comment: Rumbalski  Thanks for the quick help.  I come from a PHP background so Python lists, dicts, and tuples still throw me for a loop.  I followed your advice and get this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @tchaymore that error is from the `'href'` you're using to index in to the string. You can't do that. You can use an integer to reference a spot in the string. But not a string. I don't think your links variable is what you were hoping it was (a dictionary of the attributes in the `<a>` tag).

Comment: Oh geez -- stupid me, I stupidly used the same variable name twice in the script and one was a string and one was a list.  Thanks for the patience in helping me realize my stupidity.

Answer (score 2):

I think by "each letter inserted into a new field" you mean something like this, right?

```
h,t,t,p,:,/,/,w,w,w,.,g,o,o,g,l,e,.,c,o,m
```

If so, then `writerow()` is iterating over the characters in your string, and interpreting those as distinct columns. Try using `writerow([link['href']])` instead.

*Edit*: Looks like @Steven Rumbalski beat me to the punch on this!

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), `writerow()` takes an iterable object and, iterating over it, prints out the CSV representation of it. Your problem is a string is an iterable object. If I have:

```
mystring = 'foo'
```

Python will let me iterate over like so:

```
for c in mystring:
    print c
```

And I'll get:

```
f
o
o
```

That's a handy feature, but it's working against you in this case.

You don't want `writerow()` to itterate over the *string*, you want it to itterate over a *list of strings* -- separating the strings by commas, not the characters. In that case you'll want to make a list out of the strings like so:

```
w.writerow([link['href']])
```